# uploading files using multipart-from-data with next.js 14

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want to upload multiple images to Supabase and i am getting error with the passed data from client to server, i don't want to use another extra package such as formidable to manage this.

I am trying to upload a file using [react-images-uploading](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images-uploading)

```
 const processForm = async (data) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    // images variable is provided by react-images-uploading which is array of file
    //data_url and the file blob.
    const image_urls = images.map((item) => {
      const fileType = item.data_url.split(";")[0].split("/")[1];
      return {
        data_url: item.data_url,
        filetype: fileType,
      };
    });

    formData.append("imageList", image_urls);
    const response = await axios.post(
      "/dashboard/studio/create/upload",
      formData
    );
    reset();
  };


 <form
          className="mt-12 py-12"
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(processForm)}
          encType="multipart/form-data"
        >
```

endpoint:

```
import { createServerClient } from "@supabase/ssr";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

// I am confused here why imageList is passed as string 

export async function POST(req, res) {
  const response = await req.formData();

  function dataURLtoBlob(dataurl) {
    var arr = dataurl.split(","),
      mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
      bstr = atob(arr[1]),
      n = bstr.length,
      u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while (n--) {
      u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new Blob([u8arr], { type: mime });
  }
  const imageList = response.get("imageList");
```

```
Issue is: typeof imageList is string where it should be the javascript Array.
```

I tried to parse the imageList but din't work. Please help. thank you